# Repeated tasks for nth day of week

Tags: org-mode

How to implement a repeater in this line when writing it in an org file?

- TODO Read 1 page of book (every 4th Tuesday of the month)
  %%(diary-float t 2 4)

Whenever I mark this task as DONE, it does not log it and turn it into a TODO for the next 4th Tuesday in the month.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this your diary?  An org file?  Are you referring to an org agenda??  You've tagged this question as `calendar` and nothing more, and AFAIK there's no marking tasks as anything in the calendar.  Please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: I've clarified it now, thanks!

Comment: Have a look at habits and see if that might suit better than tasks. `(info "(org) Tracking your habits")`